# How should I say about a sunshine day?

Tags: meaning

Could anyone teach me how to express my feeling about sunshine day, like I don't like sunshine, cause it bursts my skin and make my eyes unopened? Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

First off, we don’t usually call it a “sunshine day.” We might call it a “sunny day,” or a “day with a lot of sunshine.”

I think you are trying to say something like this:

> I don’t like too much sunshine; I get sunburned and I need to squint too much.

The word *sunburn* can be used as a noun or verb. From NOAD:

> **[sunburn](https://www.wordnik.com/words/sunburn)**
>
> (*noun*) reddening, inflammation, and, in severe cases, blistering and peeling of the skin caused by overexposure to the ultraviolet rays of the sun.
>
> (*verb*) (*sunburns, sunburning*, past and past participle *sunburned* or *sunburnt*) (*be sunburned*) 
>   (of a person or bodily part) suffer from sunburn: most of us managed to get sunburnt.

and the word *squint*:

> **[squint](https://www.wordnik.com/words/squint)**
>
> (verb) look at someone or something with one or both eyes partly closed in an attempt to see more clearly or as a reaction to strong light : *the bright sun made them squint*.